# Confusion about docker ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker, so bear with me. I have written a Dockerfile that creates an image with a Java language Spring Boot service within. I am now trying to set up an entry point to start the service in the container. I chose to write an external shell script to be called as the entry point.

This is how the service is set up.

When the project is built, a zip file is produced containing the service jar, all dependency jars, config resources and a bash script used to launch the service. The script takes a number of arguments, validates them and uses them to construct and then execute a "java" command to run the service.

If you were to run this the "non-container-way", you would just unpack the zip file in a directory somewhere and invoke the script, passing the necessary arguments. The script displays "usage" information if required arguments are not present.

In the Docker container case, I'm trying to figure out how to do the same from the ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile. I specified my launcher script in the ENTRYPOINT, and it did invoke it, although, of course no arguments were passed, so the script exits with the usage information.

I can't figure out how to pass the arguments that the launcher script expects.

I get the impression that I'm missing an important detail in the usage of ENTRYPOINT.

Below are snippets of the relevant files, to try to illustrate my situation.

**Dockerfile**:

```
...
# Copy Route Assesssor service archive and unpack.
COPY target/route-assessor.zip .
RUN unzip route-assessor.zip

WORKDIR route-assessor
ENTRYPOINT ["run-route-assessor.sh"]
```

**run-route-assessor.sh**:

Rather than include a fairly lengthy script, I'll show the usage statement to give an idea of what this script expects for arguments.

```
show_usage() {
  echo "Usage: `basename "$0"` <args>"
  echo "  --port=<service port>"
  echo "  --instance=<service instance> [optional, default: 1]"
  echo "  --uuid=<service UUID>"
  echo "  --ssl [optional]"
  echo "  --keystore=<key store path> [required when --ssl specified]"
  echo "  --key-alias=<key alias> [required when --ssl specified]"
  echo "  --apm-host=<Elastic APM server host> [optional]"
  echo "  --apm-port=<Elastic APM server port> [optional]"
}
```

A container instance was created from the image:

```
[jo24447@489337-mitll route-assessor]$ docker create --name route-assessor-1 route-assessor
```

Examples of container start attempts:

```
[jo24447@489337-mitll route-assessor]$ docker start -ai route-assessor-1
Service port is required.
Usage: run-route-assessor.sh <args>
  --port=<service port>
  --instance=<service instance> [optional, default: 1]
  --uuid=<service UUID>
  --ssl [optional]
  --keystore=<key store path> [required when --ssl specified]
  --key-alias=<key alias> [required when --ssl specified]
  --apm-host=<Elastic APM server host> [optional]
  --apm-port=<Elastic APM server port> [optional]

[jo24447@489337-mitll route-assessor]$ docker start -ai route-assessor-1 --port=9100
unknown flag: --port
See 'docker start --help'.
```

Comment: This question shouldn't come without a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run a container with some default parameters you need to define these parameters in `CMD`:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "./run-route-assessor.sh" ]
CMD ["-cmd1 value1 -cmd2 value2"]
```

So you can run the container with just:

> docker run image-name

If you want to override that default parameters list with no parameters you can do it with:

> docker run image-name "''"

However the better way, would be to pass a flag to `./run-route-assessor.sh` and let the script handle how to run the Spring Boot service with no parameters

> docker run image-name -no-params